# cURL requests hanging

Tags: batch-file, ssl, curl

I have been working on a batch script for some automation in the workplace. We have a Watchguard firewall and I need to sign in via batch. My present solution is sending a cURL POST request with the details needed. This is what I am calling:

```
set address="https://watchguard.<domain>:4100/wgcgi.cgi"
set data="fw_username=<username>&fw_password=<password>&fw_domain=<domain>&submit=Login&action=fw_logon&fw_logon_type=logon"
curl -k -m 10 -X POST -d %data% %address%
```

I have left the domain, username and password out for security reasons. This works almost all the time, however occasionally the cURL request hangs indefinitely despite the -m flag used. This has, so far, only occurred after the computer's 8 hour Watchguard session has expired though this doesn't always cause the issue. Once the issue shows up, it continues to happen until the machine is restarted.

This issue seems to be correlated with a similar issue on Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer hangs indefinitely while trying to open any webpage. Chrome, Edge and Firefox have no issues loading webpages. I was tipped off to the association between cURL and Internet Explorer because of this thread: https://curl.se/mail/lib-2012-10/0184.html

When I run `curl -v -m 10 -X POST -d %data% %address%` (with -v but no -k). Doing this gives me the following output:

```
*   Trying <Firebox IP>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to watchguard.<domain> (<Firebox IP>) port 4100 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with watchguard.<domain> port 4100 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
```

When I run `curl -v -k -m 10 -X POST -d %data% %address%` (with -v). Doing this gives me the following output:

```
*   Trying <Firebox IP>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to watchguard.<domain> (<Firebox IP>) port 4100 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with watchguard.<domain> port 4100 (step 1/3)
* schannel: disabled server certificate revocation checks
* schannel: verifyhost setting prevents Schannel from comparing the supplied target name with the subject names in server certificates.
```

Is there something that I can do to make sure it goes through successfully?

cURL version:

```
curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL
Release-Date: 2017-11-14, security patched: 2019-11-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL
```

Watchguard version:
WatchguardFireBox M670 running Fireware OSv12.6.2.B631387

Comment: Have you considered doublequoting `%data%`, and `%address%`?

Comment: @Compo The content of ```%data%``` and ```%address%``` are the same on machines where it works properly and on machines where it doesn't work. There aren't any special characters in those variables causing issues.

Comment: I never said there were special characters in those specific variables, because you've kept those a secret, but you did ask if "there something that I can do to make sure it goes through successfully", and that is one thing. You should whenever possible, because it is good practice, doublequote anything which accepts it. It saves you having to determine, or guess, the possible content every time you write your commands/code.

Comment: @Compo I had some difficulty replicating the problem, but it came up again today. I added double quotes around both inputs but to no avail.

Comment: Thanks for once again providing us with information we cannot ourselves reproduce. When you are ready to provide us with information we can use to replicate your issue, feel free to update your question accordingly. Until then there is nothing we can do except for guess, and this is a technical site, not a magic act. I also didn't tell you that your specific issue was related to doublequotes, I used the comment area to provide something that you can do to make sure it goes through successfully, not everything you could do!

Comment: @Compo I have added some further details to the question. Please see the Watchguard version information and values for ```%data%``` and ```%address%```. Some information has been removed from the values for security reasons. Lastly, I noticed that this has only happened after the one of Watchguard's 8 hour sessions has expired on the machine. This is not a sufficient condition, but a necessary one.